# how pass my data to another page from ul menu content in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a navigation menu with sub menu. My menu has my product group name, and it gets data from JSON code that selects from my SQL database.

I want to save "product group id" in a variable to send it to another page that selects from product table that `ProductGroup.productGroupId  == Product.ProductGroupId`.

I want to display my products name in a submenu. This is my HTML code :

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <div ng-app="firstApp" ng-controller="FirstController">
        <li ng-repeat="x in result">
            <a class="haschild" title="" href="">{{ x.GroupName }}</a>
            <ul>
                <div ng-controller="ProductController">
                    <li ng-repeat="x in names">
                        <a title="" href="">{{ x.name }}</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

My angular app

```
<script>
    var rootApp = angular.module('rootApp', ['firstApp', 'secondApp', 'ProductApp']);
    var firstApp = angular.module('firstApp', []);
    firstApp.controller('FirstController', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("select2.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.result = response.data.records;});
    });

    var secondApp = angular.module('secondApp', []);
    secondApp.controller('SecondController', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("selectSource.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.result2 = response.data.records;});
    });
    var ProductApp = angular.module('ProductApp', []);
    ProductApp.controller('ProductController', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("selectProduct.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: Are you talking about routing? Do you want to generate URLs (Links) that contain the ID of the products? If the answer is "Yes" - [Read this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Comment: i don't know what routing is?i  am learning angular now i don't know much about it .

Comment: actually i want to save my product id in a variable and pass it to another page that select my Prodact name from my table im my sql database

Comment: Well, you must read and learn about routing, because that's what your question is all about. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Comment: ok-thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$sessionStorage**

For example:

```
$sessionStorage.projectId = Product.ProductGroupId;
```

Each page will have a controller associated. You can inject the $sessionStorage in the corresponding controller and can retrieve the saved value.

Hope this helps.